# territory analysis

Tags: arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, arcgis-desktop, analysis, network-analyst

I want to determine the territories in which customers to a bank has the shortest path. It can be done with desktop software packages or programming if it is needed. Does anybody has idea on how to start doing it?
I want to produce a map like this http://www.esri.com/industries/banking/business/~/media/Images/Content/industries/banking/graphics/DesireLineOverlay-lg.jpg
and this map only the territories are important for me.

Comment: This sounds more like Network Analyst than Spatial Analyst - do you have that extension licensed and what version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?

Comment: yes I do. ArcGIS 10. But I need to know the algorithm as well for programming.

Comment: How to do it in ArcGIS 10.0 is one question but looking for an algorithm may be best researched/posted separately.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Service Area](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Service_area_analysis/004700000048000000/) and/or [Closest Facility](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Closest_facility_analysis/00470000004n000000/) in the Network Analyst Toolbox?  This may be helpful.  The map you posted has [desire lines](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00mm00000007000000.htm), which you can find in the Business Analyst Toolbox.

Another option, if you know which point goes to which facility, is [Envelope to Polygon](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000038000000).

Answer (score 0):

If this is something that you need to do more than once, perhaps take a look at the Business Analyst Extension.

[Create Territories](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/heLP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#/Overview_of_Creating_Territories/000z000000w2000000/)

[Create Trade Areas](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/guide-books/extensions/business-analyst/exercise-3-create-trade-area-and-demo-rpt.htm)

[image]

The extension includes toolboxes which can be called from python or strung together within a model.